# AWS EMR on VPC with EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I am doing a reading on AWS EMR on VPC but it seems like it is more of design consideration for AWS EMR Service to access EMR cluster for calls.

What I am trying to do is host a VPC with ALB and EC2 instance running an application as a service to access EMR cluster.

```
VPC -> Internet Gateway -> Load Balancer -> EC2 (Application endpoints) -> EMR Cluster
```

I don't want Cluster to be accessible from outside except through Public IP of IG.  But Public IP can access only EC2 instance hosting application which calls EMR cluster on same VPC.

Is it recommended approach?

The design looks something like below. 
[image]
Some challenges I am tackling is how to access S3 from EMR if on VPC, 
and if the application is running on EC2 can it access EMR cluster, and if EMR cluster would be available publicly?

Any guidance links or recommendations would be welcome.

EDIT:

Or if I create EMR on VPC do i need to wrap it inside of another VPC something like below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest design is:

- Put everything in a public subnet in a VPC
- Use **Security Groups** to control access to the EMR cluster

If you are security-paranoid, then you could use:

- Put publicly-accessible resources (eg EC2) in a **public subnet**
- Put EMR in a **private subnet**
- Use a NAT Gateway or VPC-Endpoints to allow EMR to communicate with S3 (which is outside the VPC)

The first option is simpler and Security Groups act as firewalls that can fully protect the EMR cluster. You would create three security groups:

- **ELB-SG:** Permit inbound access from the Internet on your desired ports. Associate the security group with your Load Balancer.
- **EC2-SG:** Permit inbound access from *ELB-SG* (from the Security Group itself). Associate the security group with your EC2 instances.
- **EMR-SG:** Permit inbound access from *EC2-SG* (from the Security Group itself). Associate EMR-SG with the EMR cluster.

This will permit only the Load Balancer to communicate with the EC2 instances and only the EC2 instances to communicate with the EMR cluster. The EMR cluster will be able to connect directly to the Internet to access Amazon S3 due to default rules permitting Outbound access.

Comment: I want to host EMR on secured VPC; also the EC2 on private subnet with LB exposing it via public subnet. Is my understanding correct?  If I put EMR on private subnet will it be accessible to EC2 instance connected to LB? I am hosting a service on EC2 which would use EMR to run steps.

Comment: There is no benefit to using a second VPC. Either use Security Groups or a private subnet, as listed above.

Comment: Can EC2 hosted running on public subnet access or run service call on EMR on private subnet?

Comment: An Amazon EC2 instance can communicate with an Amazon EMR cluster if it is in the same VPC (regardless of which subnet it is in), as long as the Security Group on the EMR cluster permits it.

Comment: Do you have any good reference to host ec2 for ssh jumphost on public domain and for security groups? Im confused with SG for ec2 vs VPC

Comment: Feel free to create a new question if you require information about "SG for ec2 vs VPC". (I'm not sure what you mean by that.)